# check if topic is being published to without subscribing

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rospy, rostopic, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our project we want to write a node to check sensor nodes for possible errors. One of the checked criterion is, if the topics of the node are actually published and not just have publisher.

**Is it possible to check for published messages or publishing frequency without actually subscribing?**
The reason behind it is, that some sensors like cameras publishes large amount of data, which slow down the checknode.

Not suitable solutions:

- "rospy.get_published_topics" does not check, if the publisher is publishing at all.
- [rostopic hz subscribes the topic](https://answers.ros.org/question/237789/check-if-messages-are-published-on-a-topic/)
- time saving solutions require subscription at some point

Thank you.

---

Edit/Solution:

> I'm not sure (hence a comment), but
> there is a chance you could do this
> using [topic statistics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics).

by gvdhoorn

This is our solution. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314134/check-if-topic-is-being-published-to-without-subscribing/) by [bearot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39734/bearot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2019-01-29

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bearot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39734/bearot/) on 2019-01-30**:
It is correct that there are already subscribers to the topics. We want to check on a running system.

Thank you for your answer gvdhoorn. It is definitly new to us and what we searched for.
I will post it as answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure (hence a comment), but there is a chance you could do this using [topic statistics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-01-29**:
topic statistics are still per-connection, so if there are no subscribers, there will not be any statistics.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-30**:
If there are no subscribers, it doesn't make sense to want to check for "publishing frequency" anyway :)

I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that the OP had subscribers, but didn't want to *add* more just to check node liveness.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the software that I've worked on does sensor health reporting with the [diagnostic_updater](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_updater) library. It includes built-in functions to measuring and reporting the topic publish frequency, and reporting diagnostic errors if the publish frequency is too high or too low. It also provides a framework for reporting any other problems you might want to detect.

The only downside is that you must modify your nodes to use it; but generally the modifications are quite easy. Many of the mature ROS camera and laser drivers already incorporate diagnostics like this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-01-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bearot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39734/bearot/) on 2019-01-30**:
Thank you for your answer, but it does not work out for us.
Not every sensor node is written by us and some are missing diagnostic_updater, but it may be a solution for others.

**Comment by [TinyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39584/tinyturtle/) on 2022-11-08**:
@bearot: did you find a solution or a hack for your problem?